# Converting integers to binary with xxd

Tags: linux, xxd

I have a file, output.log, that has a list of space, ' ', separated integers ranging from [-2048,2048]. I am attempting to convert this to a binary file with xxd. I'm using the command,

```
xxd -r -p output.log > output.bin
```

However when I read the file back with xxd I lose all of the signs (-) and receive some values greater than 2048. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

edit: With sample data...

```
$ cat test
4 0 -3 -2 -1 200

$ xxd -r -p test > test.bin

$ xxd test.bin
0000000: 4012 00            @..
```

Maybe I am misunderstanding what xxd is doing, what I expected to see after the last command is to see my original input data being displayed back. Is this not correct?

With much larger data sets I will see the correct values show up from time to time but there is still a ton of noise in the output.

Comment: is it just this range of values that demonstrates the problem, or can we see it with `[-4,4]` ? If so, please edit your Q to include sample data, required output and current output as well as all coding steps in your process. Good luck.

Comment: guessing theat `output.log` is being generated by a 3rd party program? So dbl-check what the format of your data is with `file output.log`. Maybe you'll see some non-ascii char set, like UTF8 or other. That info would be valuable info for your problem. Good luck.

Comment: output.log: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

Comment: well sorry, that blows that theory. And sorry, I don't have time to dig into this further. Hopefully others will help out. There have been quite a few Qs that included `xxd` solutions, so try searching for `[bash] xxd` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some strange characters in your input source file, `xxd` works just fine with numbers.  Try looking at your data using octal dump `od -c input` to look for anything strange.

```
$ echo '-3000 -2048 -1 0 1 2048 3000' > foo.input
$ cat foo.input
-3000 -2048 -1 0 1 2048 3000
$ xxd foo.input > foo.hex
$ cat foo.hex
0000000: 2d33 3030 3020 2d32 3034 3820 2d31 2030  -3000 -2048 -1 0
0000010: 2031 2032 3034 3820 3330 3030 0a          1 2048 3000.
$ xxd -r foo.hex > foo.output
$ cat foo.output
-3000 -2048 -1 0 1 2048 3000
```